# hE: g15daemon: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Tags: synaptic

When installing various programs on synaptic and in terminal I got on 12.04 version of Lubuntu 64bit, I get this error message:

> hE: g15daemon: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

I had an error on an install in terminal but I can't trace it. Can anyone tell me what is causing it. Or how I can find what is causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed keyboard install g15daemon. Fixed.